# Set RPC Python when using elpy with virtualenv

Tags: python, elpy

I'm having trouble getting my elpy setup to work smoothly.

My current config is:

```
Elpy Configuration

Virtualenv........:  (/home/jeff/Documents/Proj/myenv/bin/)
RPC Python........: 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
Interactive Python: python (/usr/bin/python)
Emacs.............: 26.1
Elpy..............: 1.28.0
Jedi..............: 0.15.1
Rope..............: 0.14.0
Autopep8..........: 1.4.4
Yapf..............: 0.28.0
Black.............: 19.10b0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/usr/bin/flake8)

The python interactive interpreter (python) is not installed on the
current virtualenv (/home/jeff/Documents/Proj/myenv/bin/). The
system binary (/usr/bin/python) will be used instead.

[run] python3 -m pip install python
```

How do I get RPC Python set to use the interpreter in my virtual environment?

Answer (score 3):

You can set [`elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path`](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#option-elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path):

> Path to the virtualenv used by the RPC.
>
> Can be ‘default (create a dedicated virtualenv
>   .emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv), ‘system (use the system environment),
>   ‘current (use the currently active environment), a virtualenv path or
>   a function returning a virtualenv path.
>
> If the default virtual environment does not exist, it will be created
>   using elpy-rpc-python-command and populated with the needed packages
>   from elpy-rpc–get-package-list.

Also see [`elpy-rpc-python-command`](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#option-elpy-rpc-python-command).

Comment: This also works for conda envs: `(setq elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path "/home/user/miniforge3/envs/elpy-rpc/")`. I used the following env: `conda create -n elpy-rpc python=3.10 jedi autopep8 yapf black`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the same problem while setting up python-emacs on macOS. After a lot of searching found that following works with a bit of manual work.
In your config, place following

```
(use-package pyenv-mode-auto
  :ensure t
  :config
  (let ((workon-home (expand-file-name "~/.pyenv/versions")))
  (setenv "WORKON_HOME" workon-home)
  (setenv "VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR" workon-home)))
```

The part in the config is important. The pyenv-mode-auto doesn't work for me but I use it as a carrier for the setting.

Then activate the correct environments by

```
pyvenv-workon
```

which will offer you your virtual environment. This will force the elpy RPC to use the virtual environment.

Caveat - It seems that two projects with different virtual environments don't work with the above setting. I am still investigating this.
Update on Caveat - following setting for elpy might work according to the documentation

```
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook (lambda () (elpy-shell-toggle-dedicated-shell 1)))
```